# Convert PSD with custom channels to JPG

Tags: imagemagick, photoshop

### Situation

I have a large number of PSD files (~10,000) and wish to create jpegs of all of them without a gui.

### Restrictions

The conversion process needs to (eventually) happen on a headless linux/osx box and so must run from command line.
I'm running OSX/Linux environments so the solution needs to run on either(or both) of them

### Previous Attempts

For some of the files, (the more recent ones) the convert command:

`convert -flatten input.psd output.jpg`

works fine.

For some of them, (those with previews/compatibility mode)

`convert input.psd[0] output.jpg`

Also works fine.

However, when I attempt to convert from an 8bits/channel multichannel design, the convert command gives a really wacky output. I assume it's trying to use RGB but obviously that's not right!

Is there any way/tool I can use to generate a jpeg from these multichannel PSDs?
In fact, even some way to recognise that this is a non-standard PSD would be a great help as I could then treat them differently (ship off to another machine for more processing etc)

To see an example:

[image: Right]
[image: Wrong]

[image: Menu]
[image: Channels]

Answer (score 0):

You can see about getting a programatic license to Photoshop. Or, you can create actions and attempt to trigger the actions via CLI. Everything would still run through PS, but could be triggered on a headless Mac via ssh.

Comment: Thanks, I had thought of this but was unsure of how efficient it would be. I will try out some other alternatives and look into this as a backup (really want to run this headless on linux but osx is an option...)

Answer (score 0):

Try `$ convert -depth 8 rgb:image image.jpg`. [Explicit Image Format](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-processing.php)

Or maybe `$ convert -channel RGB image.jpg` to convert it to RGB before outputting.

Comment: Unfortunately both of these give the same results as above. The difficulty is that the channels are custom colours and there seems no way to detect these prior to conversion

Comment: Photoshop supports the COM interface that has binding in several languages and is available on Mac OSX (not sure about linux). You could write a python script that uses Photoshops COM interface to save any custom files as standard RGB. It would probably be quicker to do the rest of the processing with ImageMagick library (also supported by python). Regardless, you'll probably have to write some code.

Answer (score 0):

I was also facing the same problem of converting multi-channel psd/psb files to jpg. I am using photoshop CS5 on W8 system. IThe step/process to convert all such psd/psb files to jpg using photoshop was very tedious and time consuming. Creating action was and automating would also required user interaction with system.

For that I developed a VBScript and also a JavaScript which will ask the user for a folder in which all such psd/psb files are stored. The script will select one by one all the files and does all the steps which otherwise where done manually and gives user a JPG file with the same file name and desired resolution in the same folder.

This is totally a batch process and don't require user involvement. But yes, as we need the original colors of the multi-channel in our jpg also, the process uses photoshop and does all the step. So user won't be able to work on photoshop while the process is running.

There are many freeware available on internet doing this conversion, but as many as I had seen, none of them are able to retain the original color given in the psd file. As this process uses photoshop, you can get the exact jpg from the psd/psb.

You can watch the demo of this batch process at:www.youtube.com/watch?v=fmHGAW6Efew
Do let me know if you still have any doubt.

Thanks,
Gautam Chhatbar

Answer (score 0):

I have just created a Node module that deals with PSD files from the CLI. You may use it with as many files as you want with just one command.

As far as my tests went, Gimp is not really a solution and has a poor understanding of modern PSD files, and NodeJS happen to have a great new package that deals with the Photoshop format.

Instructions from the [Github repo](https://github.com/kartsims/psd-cli) :

Install it :

`npm install -g psd-cli`

Convert `myfile.psd` to a new `myfile.png` :

`psd myfile.psd`

Convert several files works as well :

`psd *.psd`

Hope you find this useful ! Package is pretty new and other cool features will be added soon, any feature requests is most enjoyed, and help with improving the code is appreciated :)